# Not getting the correct readings from any read(adc) except for adc3 after enabling the reset disable on an attiny85 in proteus and real hardware

Tags: c, avr, adc

Please be patient with me. I am only a beginner and I am still learning proper code formatting.
I have broken my program down to the very basics. Here's the issue.
I've enabled adc0 as an input connected to a potentiometer (the reset disable line an an attiny85)
but something is VERY wrong. APart from ADC3, which reads perfectly fine, the other ADC's don't give the correct results back.
If you have a look at this program its very simple. You can either set the model (in the readeeprom routine) at 1 or 3 (2 isn't really doing anything yet and just changed direction when any button is pressed). I've also tried to read the same adc multiple times, add the results and divide by however many times to get the average reading, but no change.

Model 3, is a bi-directional and the math is different to give me a routing that gives me a control with a center off and the pa, and pb values are how I set my center positions (so i have more off space in the middle)

Now, for some reason, whether it is chip setup or something I may have missed (I've never used the reset disable before) so I am assuming that this could be part of the issue? I really don't know, and even though the program is really really simple, i wanted to do it by myself so I would actually learn. But I've been stuck on this program for so long, that I'm at a point where I humbly  have to ask for more professional help. I cannot read anything apart from adc3. The other inputs give me values that I can't work with and don't correspond to what they are meant to be giving me. You can see it in the getinputs routine. That routine, I've had working before on the same multiplexor, but now it doesn't work and I have no clue why.
There is a lot of commenting, and I've included the proteus simulation as well as the schematic in the hope that someone smarter than me can work out what's going wrong and where I may have made the mistake. I have the codevision setup to run at 1mhz, as well as the simulator. Real hardware has same results as simulator. I am using codevision.
The includes tell the program what chip i am using, the eeprom read and write routines and the de[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhGNe.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f1e2.jpg)lay routine.

The proteus code is here where you can get a better idea of what's going on if you run it. Thank you in advance for any help, I really am bamboozled here and humbly ask for ayy help I can get.
[Proteus code](https://anonfiles.com/3ejdQ2x5z1/new_bi_directional_controoller_board_attiny85_pdsprj)

```
#include <tiny85.h>
#include <eeprom.h>
#include <delay.h>

void motordrive(void);
void readeeprom(void);

void getinputs(void);
void modelselect(void);

unsigned char bcount = 5;
#define ADC_VREF_TYPE ((0 << REFS1) | (0 << REFS0) | (0 << REFS2) | (0 << ADLAR))

unsigned int read_adc(unsigned char adc_input) {
    ADMUX = (adc_input & 0x0f) | ADC_VREF_TYPE;
    delay_us(10);
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
    while ((ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF)) == 0);
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIF);
    return ADCW;
}

long int controller_adc3, burn;
int  pa, pb;
unsigned char go, model, but0, but1, but2, but3, but4, but5, but6, but7, enter_programming_mode, cod;
int low, high;
char dir, ss, modelcount = 3; // this is for the eeprom read routine. Its just to make sure there isn't a number larger in there than should be.
unsigned int inputvalue_adc2, but0c, but1c, but2c, but3c, but4c, but5c, but6c, but7c, potentiometer_sensor_adc0, currentvalue_adc0;



void main(void) {
PORTB = 0x00;
DDRB |= (1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1);  // Set PB0 and PB1 as outputs
DDRB &= ~((1 << DDB5) | (1 << DDB4) | (1 << DDB3) | (1 << DDB2));  // Set PB2 to PB5 as inputs
delay_ms(100);
CLKPR = 0x80;
CLKPR = 0x00;
TCCR0A = 0xA1; TCCR0B = 0x01;
OCR0A = 0x00; OCR0B = 0x00;
GIMSK = 0x00; MCUCR = 0x00;
ACSR = 0x83;

 // ADC initialization
// ADC Clock frequency: 125.000 kHz (must be 50..200kHz)
// ADC Voltage Reference: AVCC pin
// ADC Bipolar Input Mode: Off
// ADC Reverse Input Polarity: Off
// ADC Auto Trigger Source: ADC Stopped
// Digital input buffers on ADC0: Off, ADC1: Off, ADC2: Off, ADC3: Off
DIDR0=(1<<ADC0D) | (1<<ADC2D) | (1<<ADC3D) | (1<<ADC1D);
ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN) | (0<<ADSC) | (0<<ADATE) | (0<<ADIF) | (0<<ADIE) | (1<<ADPS2) | (1<<ADPS1) | (0<<ADPS0);
ADCSRB=(0<<BIN) | (0<<IPR) | (0<<ADTS2) | (0<<ADTS1) | (0<<ADTS0);

readeeprom();  // this reads in all the basic values.
cod = 0;         // sets change of direction to 0.
go = 0;          // turns pwm off.
enter_programming_mode = 0;

while (1) {

 controller_adc3 =  read_adc(3);
 delay_ms(15);

    getinputs();                      // this gets the inputs for the multiplexed inputs. There are only 3 physical buttons and while you can multipress them together,
                                         //while you can have up to 7 different combinations with the 3 buttons, its not enough, but this routine focuses really only on but1,2 and 3 (the physical ones)




     modelselect();                // this routine checks which model is active, wether its a bi-directional or a unidirectional.
                                        //The model 3, is a bi-directional which reads from adc3 (controller input) and does the math to make sure the center is the off position. first and then activates the pwm.
                                        // model=1 means unidirectional, model2=unidirectional, model 3 is bi-directional (center position off).
                                        // This routine does the math for both types. Basicaly the unidirectional just divides by 4 to get an 8 bit value from the 10 bit input. so adc input/4 basically.
                                       // and the from within the modelsect routine, it sends the data to the motor drive routine.

    }  // This ends the While and returns it to the start.
}     // This ends the main routine, but it never actually gets here because the while is always active.





// THE SUBROUTINES ALL START HERE. The readeeprom routine works fine. Codevision has its owm readadc and read eeprom and write eeprom.

// GETINPUT ROUTINE, Starts by getting the input from the potentiometer on adc0. If its turned down to less to 10, then enter_programming_mode=1 which is currently diabled because the read adc's arent working.

// There is only 3 physical buttons.
// The way the button rotine works, is it uses but1,but2 and but3 which are set to 1, if button 1 is pressed. Same with the other 2 buttons. But0c, but1c etc are the counters for the debounce.
// if the input is between certain values, it counts as a button press. If there is any debounce, then it assumes no buttons are being pressed and resets the debounce counter.
// once one of the vales of but0c is = or > bcount, it counts it as a valid press, and it will contain to be a valid press until it's no longer pressed, where all buttons get reset because but0=1 if the input is less than 50.

void getinputs(void)
{
    controller_adc3 =  read_adc(3);       // READS OK.
    delay_ms(15);

    potentiometer_sensor_adc0 =  read_adc(0);    // this does not read ok, it gives values back that don't seem to be the correct values. Its connected to a potentiometer. I know it has a 20-50k pullup, I have a 1k pulldown pot.
    delay_ms(15);
if  (potentiometer_sensor_adc0 <10)
         {enter_programming_mode = 1;}          // this doesn't return a valid value, or the compare is faulty.

currentvalue_adc0= read_adc(1);                 // this is hooked to an acs712, which gives a reading 2.5v when theres no load. Its a bi-directional chip. This also reads incorrectly.
delay_ms(15);

inputvalue_adc2  =  read_adc(2);                // This is the multiplexed input. But1 gives 0.47v, but2 gives 0.85v and but3 gives 1.44v. This doesn't work either.
delay_ms(20);

if (inputvalue_adc2 <= 50)
        { but0c++; }        // No button has been pressed. Add one to the but0c value. That means user has finger off button or switch is off.
if (but0c >= bcount)
        {but0 = 1;}

if ((inputvalue_adc2 >= 85) && (inputvalue_adc2 <= 110))                // button one read routine
        {but1c++;}
    else if (but1c >= bcount)
        {but1 = 1; but1c = bcount;}

    if ((inputvalue_adc2 >= 160) && (inputvalue_adc2 <= 185))         // button two read routine
        { but2c++; }
     else if (but2c >= bcount)
        {but2 = 1; but2c = bcount;}

    if ((inputvalue_adc2 >= 280) && (inputvalue_adc2 <= 305))        //button three read routine
        { but3c++; }
    else if (but3c >= bcount)
        { but3 = 1; but3c = bcount;}


    // if no buttons have been pressed, then reset all the button debounce counters to 0. This part makes sure the button is depressed and is a debounce routine.

    if (but0 == 1) {
        but0 = 0; but0c = 0; but1c = 0; but2c = 0; but3c = 0;
        but4c = 0; but5c = 0; but6c = 0; but7c = 0;
        but1 = 0; but2 = 0; but3 = 0; but4 = 0;
        but5 = 0; but6 = 0; but7 = 0;
}
}





// Reads the EEPROM data in from previous usage or sets default values as generic if EEPROM is empty. This routine works perfectly.
void readeeprom(void) {
    model = eeprom_read_byte(0); delay_ms(10);
    if ((model == 0) || (model > modelcount))        //this checks the first byte of the eeprom to see if theres random stuff in it, or nothing at all (0), if so if its not previously ptogrammed,
                                                                    // then it sets all the default values up and writes them to the eeprom.
        {
            model = 1; high = 1023; low = 0; ss = 1; dir = 0;
            eeprom_write_byte(0, model); delay_ms(2);
            eeprom_write_word(1, high); delay_ms(2);
            eeprom_write_word(3, low); delay_ms(2);
        }
    else        // if there is valid data in the eeprom, then its already been programmed.
        {
            model = eeprom_read_byte(0); delay_ms(2);
            high = eeprom_read_word(1); delay_ms(2);
            low = eeprom_read_word(3); delay_ms(2);
        }
}

void modelselect(void) {
// this checks which button is activated and then sets the direction and turns the pwm on with go=1. The controller_adc3 value still holds the adc3 (controller reading)

if (controller_adc3 >= high)         //checks the input to make sure its not greater than the controller input can get to (high and low contain the highest value the input can get to as well as the lowest)
        {controller_adc3 = high;}
if (controller_adc3 <= low)          //checks the input to make sure its not lowern the controller input can get to (high and low contain the highest value the input can get to as well as the lowest)
        {controller_adc3 = low;}

 if (model == 1) {
        if (but1 == 1)
            { go = 1; dir = 0; }
        if (but2 == 1)
            { go = 1; dir = 1; }
        if ((but3 == 1) || (but0 == 1))
            { go = 0;}
    }

 else if (model == 2)
    {
        go = 1;  // turns the motor drive ON 0=OFF
        if ((but1 == 1) || (but2 == 1) || (but3 == 1))
        {
          if (dir == 1) { dir = 0; }
        }
        else {if (dir == 0) { dir = 1; }}
    }

    else if (model == 3)

        {   // this takes the controller_adc3 from the adc3 input and does the math to make the center the off position
            // and either side of the central point is accelerating the pwm the further the more the controller input is moved from the center position in both directions.
            // the motordrive() routine then makes sure if the values are low, there is a center off position. This works fine, it reads adc3 with no issues.
            go = 1;
            burn = ((controller_adc3 - low) * 1024); burn = burn / (high - low);
            controller_adc3 = burn; controller_adc3 = controller_adc3 - 512; controller_adc3 = controller_adc3 / 2;
        }

    else {  // this part is for unidirectional models like model1 and model2, the math basically just scales the input down to 8 bit rather than 10 bit, checks the high and lor of the controller inpuuts making sure its within range.
        if (controller_adc3 >= high) { controller_adc3 = high; }      //if it is out of limits, set the controller_adc3 back to the high, which is part of the joystick callibration routine, if its ok, it sends it to motordrive.
        if (controller_adc3 <= low) { controller_adc3 = low; }
        burn = ((controller_adc3 - low) * 255);
        burn = (burn / (high - low));
    }

    if (go == 0) { OCR0A = 0x00; OCR0B = 0x00; }        //if go=0 that means the button presses or switch isn't on and the pwm stops.
    else { motordrive(); }
}

void motordrive(void)
    {
        if (model !=3)
        { if (dir==0)         // it this is 0 we go in forward direction if 1 then we go in backwards direction
              {controller_adc3=burn;}
          else
              {controller_adc3= -burn;}
               OCR0A = (char)pa; // MCU Pin 5
               OCR0B = (char)pb; // MCU Pin 6
          return;
        }

              if(controller_adc3 > 0)        // Forward mode
                            {
                            pa = controller_adc3;
                            pb = 0x00;
                            }

                 else     {
                             pa = 0x00;
                             pb = -controller_adc3;
                            }

 // check wether the PWM is within range.
              if (pa >= 255) {pa = 253;}
              if (pb >= 255) {pb = 253;}


              // model c , this code gives us the center off position!!
              if (model==3)
                {
                 if (pa < 15)   {pa = 0;}   //this gives me 15 center off position in each direction.
                 if (pb < 15)   {pb = 0;}
                 goto pass;
                 }

              // model a, b and d
              if (pa < 0)   {pa = 0;}
              if (pb < 0)   {pb = 0;}

          pass:
              //Set Output, these outputs will always be between 10 and 253 on either one of the channels (pa or pb)
              OCR0A = (char)pa;   // Pin 5 of the MCU
              OCR0B = (char)pb;   // Pin 6 of the MCU
 }
```

I have tried every combination of different settings, speeds, and more. I ccan see in the data in the simulation (proteus) that it looks like it's reading values, but they are not what they should be, making me believe i've made a mistake somewhere in the chip settings. I have debounce on the inputs.
I've allowed for a range from the button presses that I've had working before. But i wonder if something has changed when i set the reset disable? or I've messed up the setup of the chip somehow?

Comment: I suggest to simplify the code. Remove everything that is not absolutely necessary to reproduce the problem with reading ADC inputs (and somehow showing the result). Please [edit] your question and show the wrong values you get and explain why these are wrong. Please create a [mre].

Comment: Separate S/W from H/W issues. You say that adc3 works. But, the others don't because they give you nonsensical values. Given that, can you tie the other adc inputs to the same source/pin as adc3? Then, you can apply the same verification sequence on those as you do adc3. Then, if they track, you'll know that your S/W is correct. If not, you need to fix your S/W. Once that's done, you can put the other adcs back on your original H/W config. Now, you are sure that the S/W works. If you get screwy values, it's an issue with connecting the device/pins.

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll give it a go and report back, thanks Craig. 
Bob it is minimal, its just got the very basics in there.

Comment: Thanks Craig. You advice helped me solve the issue. Now I'm getting the correct readings back, so thank you so much. Now I just need to find the bugs in my code... stupid bugs lol. Now I'll take bobs advice and get back to the basics and go from there. Thanks guys. both of you helped me.